# Imports for Python 3 seem to not work correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

File Structure

```
lib/
    parentClass/
        __init__.py
        parentClass.py
        main.py
        subclasses/
            __init__.py
            runner.py
            subClass.py
```

Parent class and imports and init:

```
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session
import logging

class ParentClass(object):     
    def __init__( self, resource_arn, log_level = 'INFO', resource = None ):
```

SubClass, init and imports:

```
import boto3
import logging 
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from parentClassFolder import parentClass

class subClass(parentClass):
    def __init__( self, bucket = None, arn = None ):
```

Function to call other class and do stuff:

```
import boto3
import logging 
import itertools
from . import subClass

def runner ():
    instance = subclass( parameter )
```

I am getting a

> NameError 'subClass' is not defined.

Not sure why it seems to not instantiate the parent class. Kinda new to python 3 and imports also. So not sure what went wrong, any help would be great! Thanks in advance!
So here is the structure of my files and directories.

Comment: Your last example file doesn't import anything named `subClass` (nor `subclass` which you seem to be showing here). So getting an error is not unexpected. What exactly is confusing you about the situation? Is `encrypted_auditor` supposed to be relevant? I'd also warn you that it's not generally a best practice in Python to put every class in its own module (and certainly not to create subpackages for no particular reason). Is there a particularly good reason you couldn't write your code in one or two files in a much flatter directory structure?

Comment: Sorry forgot to edit that one to the general notation.

Comment: This was the file structure that was requested by my bosses we are building an api that fits into a bigger program

Comment: It's hard to tell if the typos in your code are what are causing your errors, or if they're just an artifact of copying your code to Stack Overflow. The obvious cause of your `NameError` is that you haven't defined a class named `subClass` but instead one named `SubClass` (with a capital "S" on the front). Maybe you have other issues too, but we can't help with that without a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

So figured out the answer in my `runner.py` file I needed to have

```
from .subClass import ClassName
```

not

```
from . import subClass
```